# Possible ways to visually represent servers and the apps using them and vice versa

Tags: excel, graphics, graph, data-representation, vba

I currently have an Excel spreadsheet with roughly 40 App names and the servers, 130 in number, they run on. An example of what this looks like, below would be one row in the sheet:

```
|app name|          Servers         |
|  App1  |Server1; Server2; Server 3|
```

Does anyone know of a good way to show both what servers are being used by which apps but also which apps are using which servers?

It does not necessarily have to be in Excel, I am familiar with programming and know a number of languages so I'm not scared to get stuck into any useful libraries anyone might know of to help show this.

If all else fails I'm drawing out, by hand, a great big Venn diagram of them all but knowing my artistic skills, that really isn't going to look pretty.

The purpose of this exercise is to be able to quickly determine suitable servers to take down and if there are any apps taking up an entire server on their own etc.

Comment: Can you tell us how many servers there are plz?

Comment: I believe there are roughly 30-40 servers. I'm in the process of making a "server and their apps" list so I can tell you exact soon

Comment: list made- there were a lot more servers than i thought!!

Comment: I'd make a 2 column list - App and Server with apps repeated if they use multiple servers - and then make a pivot table.

Comment: I think pivot table is a good idea. The only way I can think of to represent that many points on a graph would be to use a scatterplot. Downside is that server and app would have to be shown as a number. You _can_ add labels but requires a macro https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/213750

Comment: Alternatively is there any sensible way you can group servers/apps?

Comment: well the servers are split into 2 groups (orange and blue for arguements sake) the majority are orange but about 20-30 are blue. Some apps use blue and orange and some are exclusive